# Loading a File in a UIWebView from NSHomeDirectory( ) ?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

How i can loading a File from NSHomeDirectory () in a UIWebview ? It's possible ? I mean loading .pdf files from the /Documents/ folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Loading a PDF into a web view isn't optimal.  Look into [**`QLPreviewController`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can download, read and store  your pdf locally in iphone application:

First create UIWebView and include <<**UIWebViewDelegate**>>

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourPDF.pdf"]; 
 if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
           // download file , here "https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf" = pdf downloading link
         NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hgjgj.pdf"]];
            //Store the downloaded file  in documents directory as a NSData format
         [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Or, if you simply want to read/load pdf from your Resource folder then simply do this :

```
     NSString*  filePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"]];
    /// or you can even read docs file as : pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"docx"]
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [yourWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [yourWebView setDelegate:self];
     yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
     [yourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how dows `NSHomeDirectory()` works, but you can Look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942185/upload-image-from-uiimageview-using-dropbox-sdk-for-iphone/8942562#8942562) to see how to get the full path of the files and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview) to see how to load a `PDF` into a `UIWebView`